# SPSS version 22: concatenating two or more columns

Tags: concatenation, spss, categorical-data

I have two columns called column_a1 and column_a2.  Both categorical (1: yes, 0: no).  I want to concatenate the two columns and create a new column called column_a.  I.e. column_a contains data from both column_a1 and column_a2.  Please assist.

Answer (score 2):

Combining binary variables is typically achieved by using a base 10 (or base 2) approach.  For your example it would be:

```
comp column_a = column_a1*10 + column_a2.
exe.
```

For five variables:

```
comp column_a = column_a1*10**4 + column_a2*10**3 + column_a3*10**2 + column_a4*10 + column_a5.
exe.
```

And so on for however many variables being combined (max 16 before you hit floating point precision issues).